# Phonegap Android App - Store Id on the phone

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a Android HTML5 App using phonegap - Is it possible to store a variable on the phone itself, which will remain regardless of whether the app is open or closed?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage is tailor made for what you are looking to do:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Comment: One question - will information stored this way remain for the life of the app/until someone clears its cache -  or will it be lost when the app is updated?